# How to import javascript based template into Java EE eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

hope you having a good day.
I am a java developer and currently learning servlets. I have downloaded a **html template** from colorlib and its hosted on my github. That template contains javascript, html, bootstrap etc.
To handle registration and other work I want to use servlets. I tried to import project in Eclipse(Java EE edition).
Steps I did are

1. Went to **File>Import>Project from GIT** (not smart import, just simple one).
2. Then I choose clone URI, entered the required details like URI, repository path, authentication details etc
3. Now in new Window its asking me to choose a project, now I want guidance for futher steps.
   Which project type should I choose?

[image]

After choosing project type what name should I put inside project name as I am entering any name I am getting an error

> Error connecting project project_name, no Git repositories found

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

P.S The server I am using is Tomcat 8.5 on localhost.

Comment: Have you added the existing local clone to the Git Repositories view first?

Comment: i downloaded the template and pushed it to my repository, now I am trying to clone it from eclipse but it is not showing to run the project on localhost server, there is only "run configuration" option. Unlike other project which I create by going to new>project.

Comment: i successfully cloned the project by smart import option, and added java by going to Configure>Convert to JPA project and selecting Java from there. I want to run this project on my localhost but couldn't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import project using smart git import.

Step-1
Open your Java Project.

Step-2
Right Click on **Your project -> Properties**

Step-3
Click on “**Project Facets**” from left menu. Click on Convert to faceted form...

Properties - Click Project Facets

Step-4
Click **Dynamic Web Projec**t and **Java**.

Step-5
Click Apply and Ok.

Step-6
Clicks on the “further configuration available…” link.
Choose location where you want to store your .html, .jsp files.
Check generate web.xml

Your project should be converted to Dynamic Web Project now.